# How would i go about creating a server that can read/write all files on the host hdd?

Tags: apache2, remote-access, file-sharing, graphical-user-interface, file-hosting

I work in the media department of a large ministry group. We frequently travel and produce TBs of data/files every quarter. Due to the high amount of Digital Media produced, most cloud-based storage options are unable to maintain our inventory. We have an early 2009 Mac Pro (4,1 flashed to 5,1) running High Sierra. I couldn't care less if We keep MACOS on the machine.

I would like to create a server With several high-capacity HDDs in a RAID config that can be accessed from anywhere provided the user provides login information. I have a decent amount of experience with HTML/CSS/JS. The Server Would have to be able to show the entire contents of the storage drives in a way that some of our less tech savvy members would be able to navigate. The user would have to be able to upload and download files.

The more free/open source programs i use, the better.
I'm currently thinking That I should install ubuntu and use apache but beyond that, I have no idea how to accomplish this. I would love for the finished product to basically require a login and then show what looks like a finder/files/windows explorer with simple drag and drop style inputs and right-click download for retrieval.

Any input is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!!

-Nick

Comment: I've voted to close because its off-topic, and more-or-less a product recommendation request.   Solutions could range from something like OwnCloud/NextCloud (a fully fledged free host-your-own Dropbox type solution with web interface as well) to a simple Apache + PHP + some file/user management script - google "PHP file manager" for a huge number of solutions.

Comment: There are also plenty of options that DONT require Apache or web - like an FTP, NFS or SMB server.  They provide tighter integration with the client OS, but have more setup requirements, and security concerns - you will most likely want to run them across a VPN like OpenVPN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up a file server is relatively simple, if that would meet your basic needs. I personally prefer Linux, but that is entirely up to you. Here's a couple of guides to get you started:

- https://www.howtoforge.com/setting-up-a-linux-file-server-using-samba
- https://www.krizna.com/centos/setup-file-server-centos-7/

The harder part - by far - of your requirement is "access from anywhere". You should *not* put your file server on the public internet; the simplest way to access your server will probably be a VPN solution to link remote clients to your private network to access the file server.